# Retrieve application.properties values via @Value in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am trying to pull data from application.properties file in Spring Boot

**application.properties**

```
host=localhost:8080
accountNumber=1234567890
```

**TestController.java**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

@Autowired
private TestService testServiceImpl;

@Value("${host}")
private String host;

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    testServiceImpl = new TestService();
    return testServiceImpl.getValue();
}
```

**TestServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

    @Value("${accountNumber}")
    public String value;

    public String getValue(){
    return value;
}
```

When I do a REST call to localhost:8080/test, I get a null value.

`TestServiceImpl` is instantiated however, `@Value` does not seem to work.

Am I missing anything?

**SOLUTION:**
All I had to do was to remove the line `testServiceImpl = new TestService();`
I am assuming it was doing that because `new TestService()` was overwriting the autowired instance of `TestService`

Comment: Great that you solved your own problem. You are welcome to post your answer as an `answer`. SO encourages people to answer your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Since you autowired `testServiceImpl`, spring container will create the bean for you and you said NO by creating instance yourself with `new TestService()` meddling with spring.

Comment: @harshavmb Yes you are right. That is what I found to be the problem. Thank you for validating my finding!

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was very simple.

All I had to do was to remove the line testServiceImpl = new TestService();

I am assumed it was doing that because new TestService() was overwriting the autowired instance of TestService.

Thank you harshavmb for verifying my solution.

Hope this helps many new Spring-ers :)

Answer (score 3):

To update :

Spring's DI achieved via @Autowired annotation.It creates the object for us.

```
@Autowired
private TestService testServiceImpl;
.
.
.

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    // testServiceImpl = new TestService(); // make comment this line 
    return testServiceImpl.getValue();
}
```